# csv file empty when running django tests

Tags: python, file, csv

It's a strange issue, I have a method where I read a csv file so I created an unit test for it, is something as simple as this:

```
def test_csv(self):
    with open(self.csv_file_path, 'rb') as csv_file:
        response = csv_parser_method(csv_file)
        assert response here
```

So if I add a `pdb` breakpoint there and check the content of `self.csv_file_path` file it's empty

```
(Pdb) import csv
(Pdb) reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=str(','))
(Pdb) [row for row in reader]
[]
```

That's strange, if I open a normal shell it has content and of course the file has content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `csv_parser_method` already reads the entire CSV file and the `csv_file` file object therefore already has its pointer positioned at the end of the file, so when you use `csv.reader` to try to read it, it gets nothing since there is no more content after the position of the end of the file.

You can use the `seek` method to reset the file pointer back to the beginning of the file so that `csv.reader` can read the file:

```
csv_file.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=str(','))
```